# How can I split weekly data to monthly using Excel/ Power Pivot?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

My Data is in weekly buckets. I want to split the number into a monthly number but, since there is an overlap in days falling in both the months, I want a weighted average of the data in terms of days that fall in each of the months. For example:

[image]

Now, in the above picture, I want to split that 200 (5/7*200 in Jan, 2/7 in Feb). How can I do that using Excel/ Power Pivot/ Dax Functions? Any help here is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fact table looks something like below. Values are associated with the starting date of the week it occurred.

[image: fact table]

Although it may actually be a more granular data, having multiple rows for each week with additional attributes (such as identifiers of a person, a store, depending on the business), what being shown below will work the same.

What we need to do first is to create a **date table**. We can do that in "Design" tab, by clicking "Date Table", then "New".

[image: date table]

In this date table, we need to add a column for starting date of the week which the date of each row is in. Set the cursor to "Add Column" area, and input following formula. Then rename this column to "Week Start Date".

```
= [Date] - [Day Of Week Number] + 1
```

Now, we can define the **measure** to calculate the number allocated to each month with following formula. What this measure is doing is:

- Iterating over each row of the fact table
- Count the number of days for the week visible in the filter context
- Add the value portion for the visible days

```
Value Allocation := SUMX (
    MyData,
    VAR WeekStartDate = MyData[Week]
    VAR NumDaysInSelection = COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            'Calendar',
            'Calendar'[Week Start Date] = WeekStartDate
        )
    )
    VAR AllocationRate = DIVIDE ( NumDaysInSelection, 7 )
    RETURN AllocationRate * MyData[Value]
)
```

Result in the pivot table will be looking like this.

[image: result]